# What Tag for salesforce basic site?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

It seems that everything is around [apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apex) [visualforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visualforce) and other 'advanced' SF sites and features.

And than comes a question like this: [Look up search on 2 custom fields instead standard name field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1417/look-up-search-on-2-custom-fields-instead-standard-name-field)
and I find myself thinking, how to tag it?

I don't think it should be [force.com](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/force.com)

so what?  and it seems that we don't have those: simple-tags

Comment: p.s. your 'visualforce' tag is spelt wrong above ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the case of this question, I think both setup and bestpractice could be used.

But as this community evolves, there will always be cases that are not easy to tag. Sometimes it may require new tags, but some questions just can't be tagged, is it truly a requirement, that every question is tagged ? I don't see it as a must for those cases in which adding not clearly appropriate tags might just cause more confusion than clarification.

Some tags and their relations to questions can also be a rather subjective relation, we all make different interpretations.

Comment: Each question needs a tag is part of SE. I don't think we can change that, and there is a lot of logic to have the 'correct' tag. as for new tags: we will always have them. My question is: how we tag questions that aren't force.com, visualforce, apex, etc.etc, a simple question about salesforce stadard objects.

Comment: I think it only makes sense, that unless you have a general tag to cover these cases (defeating the purpose), you will always have a marginal % of questions which can not be tagged. Unless you allow for a jungle of tags (again, defeating the purpose).

Comment: @Saariko - How about data-model for questions about objects?  That would cover relationships, fields, etc.

Comment: Saariko is correct; every question *must* have at least one valid tag. It's essential to our model; it helps other people understand what the questions are about and helps experts drill down content by favoriting tags they're familiar with and ignoring ones they have no expertise in. Keep up the discussions here about which tags are most useful, and when proposing new tags, please [do not create meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)  that don't actually tell you anything about the question.

Answer (score 1):

(I like Peter's suggestion of `data-model` enough that I'm elevating it to its own answer!)

> How about **data-model** for questions about objects? That would cover relationships, fields, etc.

Comment: I agree, data-model for the question in discussion is a good option.